# Setting ENUM value at runtime

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

I have a ENUM defined as;

```
public enum YesNoEnum {
    Y,
    N
}
```

I am using this for one of my values voted.

So I use it within a loop (looping over object array from query response)

```
person.setVoted(responseArray[1] != null ? YesNoEnum.valueOf((String)responseArray[1]) : null);
```

I have the setter as

```
public void setVoted(YesNoEnum voted) {
    this.voted = voted;
}
```

Now I am getting an exception if the value for `responseArray[1]` is `Y/N`

If I `debug/watch responseArray[1]` , it shows type as `YesNoEnum` and shows value as `"Y"`
It says

> cannot cast an instance of YesNoEnum to an instance of String

Comment: This is `String[] responseArray`?

Comment: how is ``responseArray`` declared?

Comment: It is an Object array Object[]

Comment: So the code is while i am iterating using for(Object[] responseArray : response.getRecords())

Comment: Never, ever, cast anything to `String` in Java, _always_ use `toString()'. Casting is in general a bad idea in Java except when you have checked the type beforehand.

Comment: Well, based on the exception message, it appears that you are storing ``YesNoEnum`` enums in your ``responseArray``

Comment: yes that is correct...it is one of the many values i am storing

Answer (score 1):

> If I debug/watch responseArray[1] , it shows type as **YesNoEnum** and shows value as "Y" It says

If I understand right the `responseArray` is array of enum `YesNoEnum`.

Therefore you get error on casting enum instance to String:

```
(String)responseArray[1]
```

You can write just:

```
person.setVoted(responseArray[1]);
```

*As a side note*

to handle `null` I would change enum to:

```
public enum YesNoEnum {
    Y,
    N,
    UNKNOWN
}
```

and write:

```
person.setVoted(responseArray[1] != null ? responseArray[1] : YesNoEnum.UNKNOWN);
```

Comment: If responseArray is of type `Object[]`as said in the question’s comments, a type cast is unavoidable. So it would be `person.setVoted((YesNoEnum)responseArray[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `responseArray[1].toString()` instead of `(String)responseArray[1]`.

Comment: `YesNoEnum.valueOf(responseArray[1].toString()) = responseArray[1]` right?

Comment: Look at the answer above, IMHO it's a much better solution.

Comment: well, in this case you dont need to ask if its `null` because you anyways provide null to method

Answer (score 0):

A `YesNoEnum` is not a String, it's an enum and you cannot cast from enum to String.  You can either change the enum to a String by calling `.toString()`, or if you know that all objects in your array are of `YesNoEnum` types then you can skip the casting alltogether and do this:

```
person.setVoted(responseArray[1] != null ? responseArray[1] : null);
```

However, if the contents of `responseArray` are of a variety of types (some YesNoEnum, some String, some Object...), you will need to determine a way to transfrom each type into `YesNoEnum` objects, something better done in another method.  As an aside, I highly recommend avoiding the use of mixed object types in your array.  It creates all sorts of problems.  Keep you arrays all of the same type.  If you need to use mixed types, then take a differnt approach.